# Sum of squares and $5\cdot2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does anyone know of a proof of the result that $5\cdot2^n$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer is always the sum of two squares?

That is, nonzero integers $x,y$ must always exist where:

$x^2+y^2=5\cdot2^n$
when $n$ is $0$ or a positive integer?

For example:

$$1^2+2^2=5\cdot 2^0$$
$$1^2+3^2=5\cdot 2^1$$
$$2^2+4^2=5\cdot 2^2$$
$$2^2+6^2=5\cdot 2^3$$

Comment: For basic information about writing math at this site see here:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 6):

Note that $5$ is a sum of two squares, for $5=2^2+1^2$.

If $n$ is even, say $n=2k$, then $5\cdot 2^n=(2^k\cdot 2)^2+(2^k\cdot 1)^2$.

Also, $10=3^2+1^2$. So if $n$ is odd, say $n=2k+1$, then $5\cdot 2^{n}=10\cdot 2^{2k}=(2^k\cdot 3)^2+(2^k\cdot 1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

$5\cdot2^n=x^2+y^2 \implies 5\cdot 2^{n+2}=(2x)^2+(2y)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two cases:
$$n=2k\implies 5\cdot 2^{2k}=(1+4)\cdot 2^{2k}=2^{2k}+2^{2k+2}=\left(2^{k}\right)^2+\left(2^{k+1}\right)^2$$
$$n=2k+1\implies 5\cdot 2^{2k+1}=10\cdot 2^{2k}=(1+9)\cdot 2^{2k}=2^{2k}+9\cdot 2^{2k}=\left(2^{k}\right)^2+\left(3\cdot 2^{k}\right)^2$$